# How Network Layer working in Swift 5 & Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, networking, xcode11, swift5

Two days already of learning how to make my own network layer to fetching data from server using API and json decoder

But after two days of many lessons online I can't find what's after creating the network layer in Swift 5,

I'm getting json data in output by `print(data)` in serviceLayer Class file but can't print the data in SwiftUI List View?

here's the serviceLayer.swift file

```
import Foundation

class ServiceLayer {
    // 1.
    class func request<T: Decodable>(router: Router, completion: @escaping (Result<[String: [T]], Error>) -> ()) {
        // 2.
        var components = URLComponents()
        components.scheme = router.scheme
        components.host = router.host
        components.path = router.path
        components.queryItems = router.parameters
        // 3.
        guard let url = components.url else { return }
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = router.method
        // 4.
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
            // 5.
            guard error == nil else {
                completion(.failure(error!))
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            guard response != nil else {
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }
            // 6.
            let responseObject = try! JSONDecoder().decode([String: [T]].self, from: data)
            // 7.
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // 8.
                completion(.success(responseObject))
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

And here is the model I'm using

```
 struct CollectionItem: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let id: Int
}
```

Comment: Usually, when updating a list, you will need to modify the list's data source. Define it as a property and attach the @State property wrapper, then add to it once your request finishes. Btw, you might have a better time using some networking framework... I've recently written one that is focused on Combine, check it out! https://github.com/borchero/Squid

Answer (score 0):

In the swift ui define a property with @State property wrapper, assign the responseObject to this property. SwiftUI automatically reloads when the @State property is set.

If you are willing to use Combine, https://dev.to/kevinmaarek/getting-started-with-swiftui-and-combine-dd8